# Downloadable content file structure

Tags: directory, uploads, filesystem, wp-filesystem

I have a bunch of files that will be used as downloadable content. Do I have to upload it as media or can I just upload to a folder through FTP? If yes, which folder?

Comment: No.  WordPress will ignore any directory that you might create to store these files in, such as `/files`.

Comment: Any advice about how to manage this?

Comment: You can in fact upload files to a folder through FTP, then write custom PHP (i.e. a plugin) to allow the downloads. But there are several excellent plugins available which do this through the WP Media Library instead of FTP and may be more reliable since you won't be the one having to maintain the code.